# Calling api request after Complete other requests

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, callback, es6-promise

```
beforeTabSwitch: async (tab) => {

            let flag = false;
            if (tab === 'PAYMENT') {
                if (this.isManualValidated) {
                    flag = true;
                    this.savePayment().then((response) => {
                        this.placeOrder();
                    });


                }
            } 
            return flag;
        }
savePayment: async function () {
            this.$http.post(this.savePaymentRoute)
                .then(response => {
                    await this.getOrderSummary();
                })
                .catch(error => {
                });
},
placeOrder: async function () {
            this.$http.post(this.saveOrderRoute)
                .then(response => {
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log('placeOrder | ' + error);
                })
        },
```

When Place Order Button Clicked **beforeTabSwitch**() which validate data & then call **savePayment**() . as savePayment request is complete then call **getOrderSummary**() then call  **placeOrder**()  request.

Call in  Order:  savePayment() > getOrderSummary() > placeOrder()

but the issue is after execute savePayment() immediately placeOrder() execution start after complete  then getOrderSummary() execute which is wrong.

i already try with Promises, callback but same issue.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to start writing some clean code. And you should either use promises approach or async-await approach. I hope this code help you:

```
beforeTabSwitch: async (tab) => {
    if (tab !== 'PAYMENT') {
        return false;
    }
    
    if (!this.isManualValidated) {
        return false;
    }

    try {
        const response = await this.savePayment();
        this.placeOrder();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }

    return true;
},
savePayment: async function () {
    try {
        const paymentResponse = await this.$http.post(this.savePaymentRoute);
        const summaryResponse = await this.getOrderSummary();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
},
placeOrder: async function () {
    try {
        const response = await this.$http.post(this.saveOrderRoute);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('placeOrder | ' + error);
    }
},
```